# How can I level a slab with floor drains?

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete

I just had the slab in my new basement poured about 3 days ago.  It turned out terrible. The entire floor is wavy and has up to 1/2 inch dips and bumps every 4 feet or so.

I would like to resurface the slab but can't take too much of the surface off since I pex tubing for my radiant heated floors below.

I have been researching self leveling overlays that I could use however I don't want certain areas 100% level as I have floor drains there.

What are my options for fixing this slab and keeping my floor drains.  I plan on acid staining the end product and don't intend on putting thing over the slabs surace.

Comment: Who put in this "wavy" slab? If it was you and/or your friends then I guess you will have a challenge on your hands. If it was a professional contractor I would get them back out to see the crap job they did. Then tell them that you expect it taken out and re-done pending legal action.

Comment: I've been considering that, after further research i'm starting to see the magnitude of the mess up.

Answer (score 1):

When you have floor drains, the installer *should* have established a fairly smooth slope toward those drains into the floor as part of the process of "floating" (levelling and smoothing) the surface of the concrete. This is slightly annoying but not difficult -- I've done it for summer-camp shower houses, as a mostly-untrained volunteer -- so a pro should have been able to handle it. If it's really their error (rather than someone tromping around in the wet cement after they levelled it but before it hardened), I agree with @MichaelKaras that it's their responsibility to figure out how to fix it.